# why is every pixel of an image are equal to 255?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am experimenting with PIL and trying to analyze the image I attached.
Since my goal is to eventually be able to recognize it via neural networks,
I expect all pixels to have different intensities and therefore different values
ranging from 0 to 255. I am not sure why, every single pixel of this image is equal to
255. How so? What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(r'key_1.jpg')
print(img.format)
print(img.size)
print(img.mode)
img # displays the image

img_sequence = img.getdata()
img_array = np.array(img_sequence)
print((img_array)) # all pixels = 255
```

[image]

Comment: You can only see the first and last few rows where the pixels are all white (255).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I printed the array's length and is equal to 160000 which means that all rows are included, aren't they ?

Comment: Try `print(np.min(img_array))`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they are not. You can see the top and the last few rows only where it shows 255 because the pixels there are white. If you try reading the same array using PIL/OpenCV, the result will show properly.

However, you can see all the results of the NumPy array using this method-

```
img_sequence = img.getdata()
img_array = np.array(img_sequence)

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
print(img_array)
```

Sample screenshot of a random part of the output I got for the same image -

[image: Output]

Comment: with your solution i am able to see all pixels values, however, it takes a long time to print it all. How would you print the same array with PIL and openCV ? Commenting out this line: np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) does not disable it and therefore takes awhile anyway. How do I disable this line ?

Comment: You don't need this line anymore. No ? This was just for an explanation. In real life scenarios, you won't be needing to view the whole array